# Como configurar spark cluster en ecs?

Tags: aws, apache-spark

Tengo una configuración de spark multimaster con zookeeper asi:

2 spark-master registrados en zookeeper y dos workers que se registran con el líder de los spark master, ademas los jobs se envían a través de livy que es una api rest.

Mi pregunta es: como se manejaría el balanceo de carga en ecs-fargate-elb teniendo en cuenta que cada componente(spark-master,zookeeper,spark-workers,livy) se despliega en un servicio ecs independiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El balanceo de carga no es posible porque spark master spark workers y livy se conectan por medio de los archivos de configuración  y la conexion se crea en compile time. La forma en que se pueden comunicar los contenedores es a través de una interface que expone el task definition llamada loopback interface que es fija y es de ip **127.0.0.1** y hostname localhost, asi el worker se registraría con el master así  **spark://127.0.0.1:7077**